# does date_default_timezone_set suffer from same process problem as setlocale?

Tags: php

Does date_default_timezone_set have the same problem as setlocale as defined in the php manual?

> locale information is maintained per process, not per thread

is this the same for date default timezone set problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source of PHP 5.3.6 it's a thread safe function.

Comment: Could you reference the file that the source declares it as thread safe?

Comment: ext/date/php_date.c for the function definition and ext/date/php_date.h for the definition of used macros DATEG, which depends on ZTS (Zend Thread Safety).